# How to pass an element as an argument in a dynamically created div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
 const div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = 'row';
  div.innerHTML = `
    <span> ${alarmName} </span>
    <br>
    <label for = "name" > Time = </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id = "alarmTime" value="${alarmTime}" disabled />
    <button class="buttonClass" onclick="removeRowThis(this,document.getElementById('alarmTime'){.value)"> delete </button>
  `;
```

then I have a removeRowThis function.

```
function removeRowThis(input : any, value: String) {
  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('alarm2')).removeChild(input.parentNode);
  alert(value);
}
```

the alert(value) in removeRowThis function is always giving me the first value. How to overcome this?

Comment: You are getting element by ID. It will return the same element with the unique ID everytime. What are you expecting? Are there more "alarmTimes"?

Comment: @TusharShahi yes, each time the first function is called, "alarmTimes" value is different and a new div is created each time.

Answer (score 0):

Better to avoid the inline handler entirely and attach an event listener when creating the button:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'row';
div.innerHTML = `
  <span> ${alarmName} </span>
  <br>
  <label for = "name" > Time = </label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="${alarmTime}" disabled />
  <button class="buttonClass"> delete </button>
`;
div.querySelector('.buttonClass').onclick = () => {
  alert(div.querySelector('input').value); // please use something other than alert
  div.remove();
};
```

Comment: `el.onclick` vs `el.addEventListener('click'` - how do you determine which one you'll use?

Comment: Both work fine. `onclick` can be a bit more handy if you want to be able to clear the listener easily without having to save a reference to the handler. `addEventListener` should be used if there's any chance of the element having multiple listeners, since that won't work with `onclick`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance then how will I pass different values of "alarmTime" in the remove function for each time a div is created. Right now, only the first value of alarmTime is getting passed for each function call.